# C#: Parse Datetime.Now to specific fromat

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I want to parse `Datetime.Now` into formatted string like

> "2016-09-01T02:00:12.7011585Z"

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")` might be what you want.  hard to tell with so little detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can't* parse `DateTime.Now`. It *already* returns a `DateTime`, not a `string`.

You can generate it's string string representation using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'` format with a proper culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture);

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```